# Derivative of a composition of functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The problem is as follows:

Find $g^\prime (2),$ given that $g(x) = f(x^2 + 2)$ and $f(e^x) = \log(\sqrt{x}).$

The answer turns out to be: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3\log6}$

I tried to use the chain rule in order to relate everything with $\log(\sqrt{x})$:

$g^\prime (x) = f (x^2 + 2)^\prime = f^\prime(x^2 + 2)\cdot 2x$

$f(e^x) = \log(\sqrt{x}) \rightarrow f(e^x)^\prime = \displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}(\log(\sqrt{x})$. Also, $f(e^x)^\prime=f^\prime(e^x)\cdot e^x$

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}(\log(\sqrt{x})=\displaystyle \frac{1}{2x} \rightarrow f(e^x)^\prime=\displaystyle\frac{e^{-x}}{2x}$

I can see that the notation gets a bit confusing, what I mean with $f (x^2 + 2)^\prime = f^\prime(x^2 + 2)\cdot 2x$ is $f(h(x))^\prime=f^\prime(h(x))\cdot h^\prime(x),$ in this case $h(x)=x^2 + 2$.

Is my reasoning correct up to now? How do I continue from here?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the logarithms are natural ones, with base $e$.

Since $f(e^x)=\log(\sqrt x)$, if we let $x=\log(u)$ (so $u=e^x$) we get
$$f(u)=f(e^x)=\log(\sqrt x)=\log(\sqrt{\log(u)})$$

or $f(x)=\log(\sqrt{\log(x)})$. Then

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log(x)}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\log(x)}}\frac{1}{x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2x\log(x)}$$

Then by the chain rule,

$$g'(x)=f'(x^2+2)\cdot 2x$$

So

$$g'(2)=f'(2^2+2)\cdot 2\cdot 2$$

$$=4f'(6)$$

$$=4\frac{1}{2\cdot 6\log(6)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{3\log(6)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$g(x) = f(x^2+2) \Rightarrow g'(x) = f'(x^2+2) \cdot (2x) \Rightarrow g'(2) = 4f'(6)$

$f(e^x) = log(\sqrt{x}) \Rightarrow f'(e^x)e^x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{2x}$

Set $x=\log(6)$, then $$ f'(6) = \frac{1}{12\log(6)}$$

Which gives you the answer you want. I think the only thing you missed above was setting $x=2$ in the first expression and setting $x=\log(6)$ in the second expression.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$g(x)=f(x^2+2)$$ and the first derivative is $$g'(x)=f'(x^2+2)2x$$ therefore we have $$g'(2)=f'(6)\cdot 4$$  now we need to compute $$f'(6)$$ we get
$$f'(e^x)\cdot e^x=\frac{1}{2x}$$ we know that $$x=\ln(6)$$ solves the equation $e^x=6$ thus we get $$f'(6)=\frac{1}{2\ln(6)6}$$ plugging this in our third equation we obtain $$g'(2)=\frac{4}{12\ln(6)}=\frac{1}{3\ln(6)}$$ like desired.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $y=e^x$, so $x=\ln y$.  Then $f(y)=\ln(\sqrt{\ln y})=\frac{1}{2}\ln(\ln y)$,

so $f^{\prime}(y)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{y\ln y}$.  Now use the Chain Rule as you're doing.